# xsl:for-each with value of not producing output

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

So I have a simple xml with some movies. I am trying to execute some xslt code to get it formatted to a table. Now the professor is insisting on using a for each loop for the genres which i find weird but ok. At any rate its the only thing i cant get to work I've reduced my code to bare bones please take a look and tell me where I am going wrong:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html><head></head><body>
 
 <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
 <th style="background-color:lightgray">Title</th>
 <th style="background-color:lightgray">Director</th>
 <th style="background-color:lightgray">Genre</th>
 
 <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select"title">
  </td>
  
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select"director">
  </td>
  
  <td>
   <xsl:for-each select="genre">
      
     <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
      
   </xsl:for-each>
  </td>
 </tr> 
 </xsl:for-each> 
 
 </table>
 </body></html></xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Movies2.xslt"?>
  
<movies>
 
 <!-- 1 -->
    <movie>      
           
        <title>Schindler's List</title>
        <director>Steven Spielberg</director>  
        <genre>Biography, </genre>
  <genre>Drama, </genre>
  <genre>History</genre>
 
    </movie>
 
</movies>
```

Comment: Your professor can impose any constraints he like on his students, but please don't try to impose them on us. We're here to help you produce good working code, not to help you achieve the next tickbox in your learning programme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues:

1. Two of your `xsl:value-of` elements aren't well formed. You need to close them and the `select` attributes should have an `=`.
2. In your inner `xsl:for-each`, you select `genre` so that is the new context. The `select` should then be `.` ([which selects the context node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)).

Example (can also be seen here http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6m):

```
<xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </td>

    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="director"/>
    </td>

    <td>
      <xsl:for-each select="genre">

        <xsl:value-of select="."/>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</xsl:for-each>
```